# Established design pattern for storing static files generated by a node app on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm building a node app that has a tiny content management system in it for forms. I have the form builder and render working great. I want to have these forms go to static HTML pages, because I don't want to query the db on every page load (tell me if this is stupid). Obviously, on heroku if I were to generate a static file, it would only be on the one Dyno. I think I need a way to output the file to a CDN. Is this the established design pattern? Should I be looking into cacheing instead? I've looked briefly at AWS S3 but I came to the same conclusion I always do: overkill. Maybe I just need to dive in?

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: What you are proposing is actually called 'caching' :). The important part here is to make sure that you have flexibility to flush/update cache manually. If there is even possibility to recache on every modify of your db forms data - that is the best.

Comment: Thanks! Ah, I see. That makes sense. Do you have a recommended technology? The only other caching I've done is with static resources or database queries.

Comment: I've used static resources for pdf.
If there is very often access to forms, and they are modified often, you might check out `redis`, or store even cached results in database (that would need to be queried by `id` instead of searching and so on).
Smart indexing helps a lot, and actually 'call' to cache stuff from database might be 'over optimising' things. You need to see actual your use case (reads/writes/updates) and pick the best option. CDN is expensive for just normal content, and is not just for storage. As well not the fastest way.

Comment: The use case is high read and very low write. I'm just thinking that reducing the number of requests to the node process is a good idea if I'm serving relatively static content. You are almost certainly right in the early stage, though

Comment: To avoid calling node at all, then you need just to make sure that cached files are updated, you can even create separate node process, that can handle that. It will simply support simple API to trigger that process from outside, and this process would go to db, get data for content required to be cached, generate static content and write to file. I actually did the same thing with PDF, and communicate using ZeroMQ. This would allow you to have good flexibility and control over caching and scalability.